# Jupyter is not executing the scratchpad cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am facing an odd issue
I just downloaded WinPython and installed the community notebook extensions
The scratchpad extension comes up with Ctrl+B but when I hit Ctrl+Enter Jupyter executes the cell that has focus in the notebook not the scratchpad cell

Any idea why is this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled all the extensions that could break Jupyter (as per the nbextensions tab) and then I enabled then one by one to see which one is breaking the scratchpad.
Magically they are all working now, including the scratchpad